# DB_REF in QGIS: Position offset

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

*DB_REF* is the official reference system for german federal railways - Deutsche Bahn (DB). For a description, see here: http://download-data.deutschebahn.com/static/datasets/aufzug/DB_REF.pdf (german)

The document mentions several EPSG codes, see below. However, trying to view any coordinates given in DB_REF (the actual EPSG code is missing very often), i come up with a position offset of 100m - 500m:

[image]

This is elevator dataset (http://data.deutschebahn.com/dataset/data-aufzug) in DB_REF assumed CRS is EPSG:5683, compared with OSM tiles and railway line network (http://data.deutschebahn.com/dataset/geo-strecke), provided in EPSG:4326 (map projected to EPSG:3857). Elevators should be placed on the platforms, between the lines.

Same offset issue occurs when I attempt to save my own data in DB_REF using QGIS - they get an offset to external DB_REF data.

Am I missing any DB_REF CRS? Or could the DB_REF definitions used by QGIS be wrong?

---

EPSG codes:

> - 1081   Deutsche Bahn Reference System
> - 5825   DB_REF geocentic
> - 5826  DB_REF to ETRS89
> - 5681   DB_REF geografic 2D
> - 5830   DB_REF geografic 3D
> - DB_REF / 3-degree Gauß-Krüger
>
>   - 5682   zone 2 (E-N)
>   - 5683   zone 3 (E-N)
>   - 5684   zone 4 (E-N)
>   - 5685   zone 5 (E-N)
> - DB_REF / 3-degree Gauß-Krüger+DHHN92 height
>
>   - 5832   zone 2 (E-N)
>   - 5833   zone 3 (E-N)
>   - 5834   zone 4 (E-N)
>   - 5835   zone 5 (E-N)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved in PROJ master (https://github.com/OSGeo/proj.4/issues/1167) - correct DB_REF will be available to QGIS users after PROJ version 6.0 is rolled out on 2019/02 (- or by building PROJ-master and GDAL from source).

Thanks to AndreJ for the issue on PROJ and his remarks to my post.

Comment: But only with current PROJ master, or not?

Comment: Yes, and PROJ master is being installed with current QGIS installations / updates, right?

Comment: No, current builds come with the latest PROJ **release** version 5.2. **Master** is the base for the next release version 6.0. And it needs a new GDAL release version as well. Until then, you have to compile PROJ and GDAL from master sources yourself to get the changes.

Comment: See my edit of my answer.

Comment: If you type `gdalsrsinfo EPSG:5683` inside the OSGEO4W shell, do you get datum shift parameters?

Comment: Oh no ... of course you are right and there are no datum shift paramters. I mistakenly assumed it would be solved - what I saw in my test project was not the result of a corrected EPSG:5683 but the workaround PROJ string you suggested above.

Comment: Edited my answer again (in order not to confuse other readers with my mistakes)

Answer (score 3):

The DB_REF definitions in QGIS are wrong (at least in QGIS2).

They are missing any +towgs84 parameter, which is necessary for the DHDN datum.

Instead of EPSG:5683, take EPSG:31467 which has the correct datum shift values.

---

The linked document lists datum shift values that differ from EPSG:31467, so you might use these PROJ strings instead:

For GK2:

```
+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=6 +k=1 +x_0=2500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=584.9636,107.7175,413.8067,1.1155214628,0.2824339890,-3.1384490633,7.992235 +units=m +no_defs
```

For GK3:

```
+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=9 +k=1 +x_0=3500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=584.9636,107.7175,413.8067,1.1155214628,0.2824339890,-3.1384490633,7.992235 +units=m +no_defs
```

For GK4:

```
+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=12 +k=1 +x_0=4500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=584.9636,107.7175,413.8067,1.1155214628,0.2824339890,-3.1384490633,7.992235 +units=m +no_defs
```

Comparing with datum transformations with BETA2007 and EPSG:31466, DB_REF is about half way between them. BETA2007 is 1.2 meters away, ESPG:31466 0.5 meters.

Comment: That seems to work, but how can I be sure it's truly accurate? I get no official information on DB_REF except for the document cited above. The wrong definition of DB_REF is widely spread, covering QGIS 3, epsg.io (http://epsg.io/5683) and other EPSG registries.

Comment: You find the correct datum shift in the document you linked under (4).

Comment: So this contains alle the information I need to build my own proj4string for a custom CRS definition in QGIS? Great. I'll dig into it and try. I have to shelve the topic a little bit, but I'll come back with my results.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/OSGeo/proj.4/issues/1167